# Scrollable text in Android widget

Tags: android, scroll, textview, marquee

I have created a widget to display some long text. I want this text to have "marquee" effect . I've already set TextView propertie ellipsize="marquee" but it doesn't works .
Any idea?

Edit: For example Stocks widget of HTC

Answer (score 0):

The `marquee` effect will only be seen if the `TextView` is selected, or is a child of a parent that is selected, IIRC.

Comment: Ok, I need another solution which can do that without selection